Why Java Encoder and Decoder Not Working Correctly
How to properly encode strings in java? I'm trying to encode the letter Ü in utf-8 and I'm getting garbage results - d093d19a instead of C39C. What could be the problem?
package org.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class Main {
    public static String convertStringToHex(String str) {
        char[] chars = Hex.encodeHex(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        return String.valueOf(chars);
    }

    public static String convertHexToString(String hex) {

        String result = "";
        try {
            byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(hex);
            result = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (DecoderException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Hex format!");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("encoder Ü: " + convertStringToHex("Ü"));
        System.out.println("decoder Ü error: " + convertHexToString("d093d19a"));
        System.out.println("decoder Ü: " + convertHexToString("C39C"));
    }
}

Output:
encoder Ü: d093d19a
decoder Ü error: Ü
decoder Ü: ?

I work in windows. I know that windows uses its own encoding, can this affect the final result?

[edit] the question to add the output formatted as [code block].

For capital U with diaresis (umlaut) try \u00DC instead of Ü in the java code. It might be that the editor uses an other encoding than the compiler (error).

Also since java 17 HexFormat exists, see for several tedchniques Baeldung's https://www.baeldung.com/java-byte-arrays-hex-strings

Try it in Powershell, first doing [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding

You have a non-UTF8 encoding in your editor and in your output display. Your convertHexToString("C39C") definitely creates the string "\u00DC"` irrespective of your Java default charset. So, since you can't display "Ü", you're not using the same encoding in your output window as Java is using to output it.

I'd expect C39C to be the hex encoding of its code point, not of the individual bytes that make up its value in UTF-8.

@LouisWasserman no, C39C is passed to a Commons Codec util that treats each pair of hex digits in the string as a single byte.
